# What is the difference between apache Ambari Server and Agent

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

What is the difference between Apache Ambari Server and Agent?

What is the role\tasks of the server vs Agent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ambari server collects informations from all Ambari clients and sends operations to clients (start/stop/restart a service, change configuration for a service, ...).

Ambari client sends informations about machine and services installed on this machine.

You have one Ambari server for your cluster and one Ambari agent per machine on your cluster.

If you need more details, Ambari architecture's is explained [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12559939/Ambari_Architecture.pdf)